# ¿Cómo redireccionar a otra vista si la session no se ha iniciado?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación el Lararvel donde al ingresar el usuario y contraseña se crea una `$_SESSION` de PHP. En caso de que la session no esté creada me gustaría que el usuario no pueda acceder a ninguna otra dirección url de la página y que al intentarlo sea redireccionado al inicio.

Para esto agregue este código al comienzo del layout de las vistas:

```
<?php
    if(!session('logged')){
        return redirect('/');
    }
?>
```

Este es el guardado de la session en caso de que el loggin sea exitoso:

```
 session(['logged' => true]);
```

Sin embargo, la aplicación entra en el if (o sea que reconoce que la session no está iniciada), pero no redirecciona al usuario, sino que se mantiene en la misma url y deja la pantalla en blanco, tal como muestro en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, después de estar leyendo un poco entendí que el mejor camino es para realizar esto es con un middleware:

Creo el siguiente middleware:

```
class isLogged
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!session('logged')){
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

luego creo un grupo de rutas y agrego todas aquellas que yo quiera que sean sometidas al middleware isLogged:

```
Route::middleware(['isLogged'])->group(function () {
    Route::view('/menu', 'menu');
    Route::view('/corte', 'planillas.corte');
    //etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

lo mejor que puedes hacer, es usar el sistema de autenticación de *Laravel*, es muy sencillo y personalizable, puedes configurar el **driver**, que utilizara laravel para almacenar la `session` del usuario en el archivo `config/auth.php`

```php
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false
        ]
    ],
```

Allí configuras el guard que usaras, en tu caso el **web**; una vez hecho esto solo tienes que usar el **middleware** `auth` en tus rutas o controladores y puedes personalizar la ruta a la que se redireccionaran los usuarios en `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` y en `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

Ejemplo de `Authenticate.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('custom.route');
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes encontrar mas información [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication):